# How do I clear all the Source (aka View) tabs in Rstudio?

Tags: user-interface, rstudio

I did a *bad thing* and ran View(row) 8000 times using apply.

Now I have 8000 tabs in my Source pane (top left) in Rstudio.

Does anyone know how to clear them all in one fell swoop? Otherwise I'm doomed to control-W A LOT.

Things I've already tried:

- Moving .RData
- Moving .Rhistory
- Google searching "rstudio clear source" "rstudio delete tabs" etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I know that if you hit

> Ctrl + Shift + W

it will close all the tabs. The same option is also under

> File > Close All

So just save the tab you wanted and close all.

Comment: I did similar mistake, but opening only 25 new tabs. Maybe it can be useful for anybody who wants to close an individual tab in Windows. I used the combination:  `Ctrl+W` (for mac is: `Command+W`).

Comment: Is there any way of closing windows from the command line, though? If, say, I wanted to open a window in a function (`View(x)`) and then close it again?

Comment: I came across the same problem today and noticed that there is also a combination to close all but current (Alt+Shift+Cmd+W) which might be also very helpful from time to time!

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+W` can be used for windows to close all table except current one.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer here just in case anyone needs it.

When I tried `File>Close All` my laptop froze because of the sheer amount of tabs I had open.

I finally found the location where Rstudio is storing the tabs to restore upon reopening.

Navigate to `.rstudio-desktop/sdb/` (stored in my root). I had three folders there, which if I open and peek into one of the files sure enough I could see my `View()`'d objects. I moved these three folders to a temporary location (to be deleted when I am feeling brave) and recreated the empty folders. Hey presto, I can now open Rstudio with no tabs.

Comment: I had a similar problem - not 8000 tabs, but some tabs had very very large lists displayed. I am on windows though so needed to rename the user\user.name\appdata\local\rstudio folder (to rstudio_old) then restarted rstudio and it created a NEW one and worked great!