# Efficiently get rid of all or some objects in RStudio Script pane

Tags: r, rstudio

I open dataframes all the time in RStudio using `View(df)` or `View(list)` which pops open a window in my RStudio script pane as with `MASTERstat1` `MASTERextract` and `MASTERbackout1` in the image below:
[image]

**Is there a way to close all the windows that are NOT SCRIPTS?** I inevitably forget to close them and get a ton of them, and stuff gets cluttered.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's [not currently possible](https://community.rstudio.com/t/close-tabs-opened-with-view-only/5668/2) in RStudio, at least as of a month ago.

One sub-optimal workaround mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127455/6481442) is to make sure your script tabs are saved and then to close all tabs using `Ctrl+Shift+W`.

My personal preferred method for closing a lot of unwanted tabs quickly is to use `Ctrl+Tab`/`Ctrl+Shift+Tab` for navigating between tabs and `Ctrl+W` for closing the current tab.

Edit: also potentially useful is `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+W`, which closes all but the current tab.